# How do I post data to a SQL database using a URL?

Tags: php, python, sql, sql-server, csv

I have a client who has a feed of leads which have Name, IP, Address, OptIn Time/Date, and I want them to be able to post the data to my hosted SQL database. If you are familiar with lead generation you will get what Im trying to do.

Id also like to know if its possible to write a script and place it on my server so that when someone posts a CSV file to it I can have the script automatically post the data in the CSV to the SQL server.

Is this possible? And are there any tutorials our reference manuals, sources, etc. I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is Yes.

You can go about this two ways:

1. Write an API for your database which is consumed by those wishing to search/write/query your database. To do this, you can use any language that you are comfortable with. PHP, XML and Python are not interchangeable.  XML is a format specification, it describes what the data should look like when its being transported between two systems. So you can use any programming language that provides XML libraries to write your code.  In addition to XML, JSON has emerged as the more popular transport format especially for mobile and web applications.
2. The second option is to use a service like [apigee](http://apigee.com/about/), [google cloud endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) and [mashery](http://www.mashery.com/) which will automate a lot of this process for you. Each requires its own amount of effort (with google cloud endpoints perhaps requiring the most effort). For example apigee will automatically create an API for you as long as you can provide it access to your data source.